# Rocketr IPN with C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So i am fiddling with this website's IPN function to see if i wan't to incorporate it to some dumb project my friends and i are working on. To be honest i don't know much C# in depth, i'm fairly new to the language (a few months of coding practice).
This is the PHP sample they give out on how to use it:
https://github.com/Rocketr/rocketrnet-ipn-php/blob/master/example_rocketr_ipn.php

I am trying to make a receiver like that in MVC 5. I have the Model setup with a function when the IPN hits the server page to process the request but it seems to just fail out everytime and not write any raw data i am trying to capture to the logs.

```
// GET: Purchases/Incoming
    public void Incoming()
    {
        var ipnDebugLog = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "/Logs/IPN/debug.txt";
        var testIPNKey = "the hash here";
        byte[] ipnToByes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(testIPNKey); // IPN string to byteto hash with
        var recvdIPN = Request["HTTP_IPN_HASH"];
        HMACSHA256 testHash = new HMACSHA256(ipnToByes); // Setting testHash to IPN secret string
        string ipnHeader = Request["IPN_HASH"];
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ipnDebugLog))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(ipnHeader);
            foreach (var reqHead in ipnHeader)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(reqHead.ToString());
                sw.WriteLine("JSON String: " + Request["HTTP_IPN_SECRET"]);
                sw.WriteLine(recvdIPN);
                sw.WriteLine("From: " + GetIPAddress());
            }
        }

    }
```

So this is just me trying to get the data being sent from Rocketr. On the site it states:

> To verify the integrity of the payload, we will send an HMAC signature
>   over a HTTP header called “IPN_HASH”. The HMAC signature will be a
>   signed json encoded POST object with your IPN secret. You can see how
>   to verify the signature in the example_rocketr_ipn.php file in this
>   repository.

Am i just to dumb and new to understand C# to function like this? I feel like i'm on the right track to reading the raw data but i'm probly wrong?

**So to sum up the question**
Am i doing the incorrect way to read a raw custom HTTP header called IPN_HASH? Going off of the PHP example they used isset to read a server variable header labled HTTP_IPN_HASH right?

Comment: Is that your controller? Why dont you use binding with the FromHeader attribute?

Comment: HTTP headers are in `Request.Headers`. You're doing a `foreach` on a `string`(?), _etc_.

Comment: Like i said i'm very new to C# and ASP.net, i was able to list all header data and body data and Rocketr reported the incorrect header name fields so that explained alot. I have the data being read correctly now so i can manipulate it on the backed. BUT i still need to figure out how to deal with this HMAC512 thing.
So i have to convert this
$hmac = hash_hmac("sha512", json_encode($_POST), trim($IPN_SECRET));
To a function in C# which i have only gotten to:
HMACSHA512 myIPNHash = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myIPNKey));
Which apparently doesn't work... when i call .hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So i have to convert this `$hmac = hash_hmac("sha512", json_encode($_POST), trim($IPN_SECRET));`

Try this (make adjustments as needed/necessary):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Foo
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void PhpHashTest()
        {

            string IPN_SECRET = "I-am-the-secret";

            //Mocking some HTTP POSTed data
            var someFormUrlEncodedData = "order_id=1234&product_title=Hello%20World&product_id=Sku123";

            //Mocking json_encode($_POST)
            var data = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(someFormUrlEncodedData);
            var dictionary = data.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => data[key]);

            //{"order_id":"1234","product_title":"Hello World","product_id":"Sku123"}
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);          

            byte[] bytes;
            using (var hmac512 = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IPN_SECRET)))
            {
                bytes = hmac512.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json));                        
            }

            //will contain lower-case hex like Php hash_hmac
            var hash = new StringBuilder();
            Array.ForEach(bytes, b => hash.Append(b.ToString("x2")));           

            //Assert that Php output exactly matches implementation
            Assert.IsTrue(string.Equals("340c0049bde54aa0d34ea180f8e015c96edfc4d4a6cbd7f139d80df9669237c3d564f10366f3549a61871779c2a20d2512c364ee56af18a25f70b89bd8b07421", hash.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal));
            Console.WriteLine(hash);
        }
    }
}
```

Not a PHP dev - this is my "Php version":

```
<?php

$IPN_SECRET = 'I-am-the-secret'; 

# 'order_id=1234&product_title=Hello%20World&product_id=Sku123';
$json = array('order_id' => '1234', 'product_title' => 'Hello World', 'product_id' =>'Sku123');

echo json_encode($json);
echo "<br />";

$hmac = hash_hmac("sha512", json_encode($json), trim($IPN_SECRET));

echo $hmac;

?>
```

Hth....

Comment: PERFECT!!! I have never even had to try something like this haha and i don't know much PHP either. This worked great, did some tweaking of the strings and such but this snippet worked perfect thank you so much. I can actually kinda understand it now too lol.